# Twitter user_timeline. Hide tweet's url in text field

Tags: json, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working with Twitter's API to retrieve a list of tweets from a Twitter account.

I'm using this: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

I get the JSON response (http://pastebin.com/raw/zqyUuXcG) but in the text field (at the end of it) I also have the url to the tweet itself. 
I'd like to avoid that because I want to keep the text clean and put the url in an hyperlink (like on date or on the container div).

I couldn't find a way to avoid url to be included in the text field. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the method you want to use *after* you obtain a JSON response, but doesn't look like you have direct control over URL placement straight from the API.

You could use grep to either extract the URL or filter it out from the text field.

For example, in R, this chunk of code would remove everything after and including "https":

```
gsub( "https.*$", "", textfield)
```

Comment: But in this way all the urls will be wiped out! I'd like something that only excludes the url of the tweet itself. I thought there was a way to do that through the API... If not, yes, I should do something like yours but then it will be difficult to differentiate urls

Comment: You could create a negative lookahead to only exclude the last instance of "http". In the textfield, the url of the tweet itself is always last.
This is the pattern that worked for me: `http(?:.(?!http))+$`. You can play around with it [here](http://regexr.com/3d4ff)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that! Thank you very much!